# I got setSoftInputMode error in unity android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public class ScreenAndroid : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Start()
        {
            ScreenAndroidSetting();
        }

        void Update()
        {
            ScreenAndroidSetting();
        }

        public void DVP()
        {
            ScreenAndroidSetting();
        }

        void ScreenAndroidSetting()
        {
            if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android)
            {
                return;
            }

            AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
            AndroidJNI.PushLocalFrame(0);
            try
            {
                using (AndroidJavaClass jcUnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
                using (AndroidJavaObject joActivity = jcUnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                {
                    joActivity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(RunOnUiThread));
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                AndroidJNI.PopLocalFrame(System.IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }

        void RunOnUiThread()
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass jcUnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            using (AndroidJavaObject joActivity = jcUnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
            using (AndroidJavaObject joWindow = joActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow"))
            {
                joWindow.Call("setSoftInputMode", 32);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a c# code (Unity) to push the screen up when the keyboard appears but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to fix it?